# Compressing and merging multiple lines of VBA code to one line

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please let me know how to write the following two sets of codes (each set) in one line?

```
   newb.sheets("Sheet1").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   newb.sheets("Sheet2").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   newb.sheets("Sheet3").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   newb.sheets("Sheet4").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

   LastRow1 = sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
   LastRow2 = sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
   LastRow3 = sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
   LastRow4 = sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Why does it need to be on one line? And does a function/sub call count as one line?

Comment: Because I have 28 sheets in a workbook.  So there will be 28 lines of code.  Hence I am looking for a best way to reduce the number of lines.  I just wanted to become a best and smart programmer.

Comment: Maybe you should add that to the question for clarity, though @SivaCharan and simpLEMAn seemed to understand it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple, you can do using For Loop

```
For i = 1 To 4
   newb.sheets("Sheet" & i).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   LastRow1 = sheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
Next i
```

Here, `4` represents number of sheets

In other way, you can get the count of total sheets using **`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`**

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
   newb.sheets("Sheet" & i).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   LastRow & i = sheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
Next i
```

Comment: Second one even more helpful.  Thanks again :)

Comment: This will overwrite LastRow1 Everytime. And not return lastrow for all sheets only the last.

Comment: That's not going to work, you'd be better of with a list or collection. Also if you remove the "Sheet" from the sheets statement it will run faster because it will use the index of all the sheets instead of using a look up to get the sheet with the name.

Comment: Yeah I know.  This looking is helpful only for 1st line and not for finding last row, because for each sheet LastRow values should be stored.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to construct variable names via concatenation as in "LastRow & i". A simple workaround would be an array.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
Dim LastRow() As Long
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        ReDim Preserve LastRow(i-1)
        LastRow(i-1) = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
Next i
```